# Custom collection as datagridview datasource

Tags: vb.net, collections, datagridview

I am learning to create custom class and collection class. Now to put my newly learned skills to the test, I would like to display the collection class in a `datagridview` object.

If I set the collection class as `datasource`, no data is populated in the `datagridview`..

My sample contains a purchase class object containing some properties. The purchases are collected in one collect class called purchases.

The datagridview should show all purchases in the collection to the user.

Below is my code.

```
Public Class PurchasesEditor

Private Property Purchases As New Purchases

Public Sub New()

    ' This call is required by the designer.
    InitializeComponent()

    ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.
    Dim oPurchase As New Purchase
    oPurchase.ID = Purchases.Count + 1
    oPurchase.Description = "Test item"
    oPurchase.Supplier = "Wallmart"
    oPurchase.PurchaseDate = "13/09/2018"
    oPurchase.VAT = 21
    oPurchase.Amount = 100

    Purchases.Add(oPurchase)

    dgvPurchases.DataSource = Purchases

End Sub

End Class
```

Purchases collection class
    Public Class Purchases

```
Private PurchaseList As New List(Of Purchase)

Public Sub Add(purchase As Purchase)
    PurchaseList.Add(purchase)
End Sub

Public Function Remove(purchase As Purchase) As Boolean
    Return PurchaseList.Remove(purchase)
End Function

Public Function GetEnumerator() As IEnumerator(Of Purchase)
    Return PurchaseList.GetEnumerator
End Function

Public ReadOnly Property Count() As Integer
    Get
        Return PurchaseList.Count
    End Get
End Property


End Class
```

Purchase class
    Public Class Purchase

```
Public Property ID As Long
Public Property Description As String
Public Property Supplier As String
Public Property PurchaseDate As Date
Public Property Amount As Decimal
Public Property VAT As Double

Public ReadOnly Property VATamount As Decimal
    Get
        Return Amount + Amount * (VAT / 100)
    End Get
End Property


' TODO custom collection
'Public Property AttachedDocuments As List(Of Document)

End Class
```

Comment: There's absolutely no reason to create that `Purchases` class.  It does nothing for you and is the reason you see no data.  Get rid of it and simply create a `List(Of Purchase)` in your first code snippet.

Comment: At the moment it does nothing. It's a Sample, I would like to create reporting operations in the Purchases class later. For example: export all purchases from supplier X. Also the class that contains the datagridview settings is from the front-end portion (windows form) and I use a Class library to run batch routines without having to run the front-end. Thanks for the input though I thought about this but it seemed not the best way to handle things.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that your `Purchases` class is NOT a collection.  It CONTAINS a collection, i.e. the `List(Of Purchase)` you assign to the `PurchaseList` field, but that is hidden inside.  The `DataGridView` won't magically get at that data and display it.

In order for your class to be a list/collection then, at the very least, it must implement the `IEnumerable` and/or `IEnumerable(Of T)` interface.  You can also implement `ICollection` and/or `ICollection(Of T)`, which extend the previous interfaces.  You can also implement `IList` and/or `IList(Of T)`, which extend the previous interfaces even further.  In order to be useful in binding to a `DataGridView` you would need to implement `IList` and you should implement `IList(Of T)` too.

You can implement those interfaces from scratch if you want but you shouldn't.  The `System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection(Of T)` class provides a base implementation of `IList` and `IList(Of T)` that you can extend by inheriting and then overriding and/or adding your own functionality.  If you are aiming to bind specifically then you should instead inherit the `System.ComponentModel.BindingList(Of T)` class, which inherits `Collection(Of T)` and adds specific binding support by implementing the `IBindingList` interface.  If you need filtering functionality too then you can implement the `IBindingListView` interface as well.

Unless you need specific custom functionality, you should just stick with the `List(Of T)`.  If you use one in data-binding scenarios though, it doesn't raise the events required for the UI to update on changes.  In that case, you can bind the list to a `BindingSource` and bind that to your UI, then call methods like `ResetBindings` as required to update the UI.

I suggest that you read [this](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?548061) for more detailed information.